# How do I convert this code from Tensorflow version 1 to version 2?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, mnist

I am trying to run a code on tensorflow that was previously written on tensorflow version 1 using MNIST dataset, but I keep getting errors because some commands are not compatible with tensorflow version 2 which is what I am currently running. My question is how do I rewrite this code in tensorflow version 2 so that I can get the same output as the one below?

[image: code and the output]

Some of the options I have tried were installing Keras, an older version of TensorFlow and I also tried different commands to download the MNIST dataset.

This is one of the codes that I tried but it didn't work

import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

tf.disable_v2_behavior()

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow official site have a detailed [article](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) for this migration.

Answer (score 0):

In `TensorFlow 2.x`, You can get most of the above code operations done with minimal code or with a set of defined [APIs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras) for the same task as -

- importing the built-in TensorFlow dataset(`tf.keras.datasets`),
- model
  building with defined layers(`tf.keras.layers`),
- model compilation
  with the built-in loss(`BinaryCrossentropy, SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` etc), optimizers(`adam, sgd` and with
  the available accuracy metrics.

Please have a look at this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) for your same model in `TensorFlow 2.x`  where you will get detailed understanding on each operation by replacing the `fashion_mnist` dataset with the `mnist` dataset.

Also you can see there is significant improvement in **accuracy** of the model using `TF 2.x` as shown here:

```
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)

print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

**Output:** (Attaching the [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/06725676c0632a213834e3c86311a0eb/74944486.ipynb#scrollTo=lqY32rpaCPoI) for the same above code in `TF 2.x` as a reference)

```
313/313 - 1s - loss: 0.0922 - accuracy: 0.9779 - 646ms/epoch - 2ms/step

Test accuracy: 0.9779000282287598
```

You can take help from this [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)  for how to convert other similar  APIs from `TF 1.x` code to `TF 2.x`.